# insert a column from one table to another with constraints

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 2 tables: *legend* and *temp*. temp has an ID and account ID, legend has advent_id, account_id and other columns. ID in temp and advent_id in legend are similar. account_id column is empty and I want to import the relevant account_id from temp to legend. I am using PostgreSQL.

I am trying the following query, but it is not working as I am expecting. New rows are getting created and the account_id's are getting added in the new rows, not to the corresponding advent_id.

```
insert into legend(account_id)
select temp.account_id
from legend, temp
where legend.advent_id=temp.id;
```

It is inserting the account_id in the wrong place, not to the corresponding advent_id.

I am using the following query to check:

```
select advent_id, account_id from legend where account_id is not null;
```

What exactly is the problem in my insert query?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are trying to modify existing rows, rather than add rows, then you need an `UPDATE` query, not an `INSERT` query.

It's possible to use joined tables as the target of an `UPDATE`; in your example:

```
UPDATE legend
JOIN temp
SET legend.account_id = temp.account_id
WHERE(temp.id = legend.advent_id);
```

Comment: `JOIN` is pretty critical here - I suppose if you just wanted to update one particular `advent_id`, you could do something with subqueries

Comment: It is giving me an error:

update legend_backup join temp set legend_backup.account_id=temp.account_id where temp.id=legend_backup.advent_id;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "join" at character 22
LINE 1: update legend_backup join temp set legend_backup.account_id=...

Comment: This query worked for me :) not sure if its perfect though :|
update legend_backup set account_id=temp.account_id from temp where (temp.id=legend_backup.advent_id);
The query that I am using to check is giving me a better output. Am I on the right track?

Comment: I modified the checking query to : select advent_id, account_id from legend_backup where account_id is not null;